# Erro de Dominio UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN:Domain not whitelisted by project

Tags: java, android, firebase, oauth

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo no qual desejo fazer a autenticação (login), via e-mail sem senha.
Não obtive muita documentação atual sobre isso, então peguei o exemplo do firebase em si no github.

O problema é que, quando vou colocar o e-mail, ele retorna um erro no meu Log:

com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN:Domain not whitelisted by project ]

Já pesquisei muito sobre esse erro, e o que eles respondem é que os domínios precisam ser atualizados.

Não tenho um domínio pago, então estou usando os gerados pelo próprio Firebase.

As codificações são as seguintes:

Android Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="https://telefones-c6ce7.web.app/"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                android:host="http://telefones-c6ce7.web.app/"
                android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.firebaseapp.com"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.firebaseapp.com"
                    android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.web.app"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.web.app"
                    android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="localhost"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="localhost"
                    android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="https://a0800restinga.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="http://a0800restinga.page.link"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

veja que coloquei vários links de domínio que achei interessantes para fazer testes.

Ao clicar em meu botão, ele tem o seguinte código:

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
                ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                        // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
                        // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
                        .setUrl(url)
                        // This must be true
                        .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                        .setAndroidPackageName(
                                "com.joel.a0800restinga",
                                true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                                "1.2.6"    /* minimumVersion */)
                        .setDynamicLinkDomain("a0800restinga.page.link")
                        .build();


        firebaseAuth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "email? " + email);
                        //Void v = task.getResult();
                        //Log.d(TAG, "void is " + v);
                        boolean emailWasSent = task.isSuccessful();
                        if (emailWasSent) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                        } else {
                            Exception e = task.getException();
                            Log.d(TAG, "There was a problem");
                            Log.e(TAG, "msg ", e);
                        }
                        setText(emailWasSent);
                    }
                });
```

no qual, o seturl estou gerando, e direciona corretamente como já analisei no clique.
Eu acredito que as outras informações estão corretas.

Por fim, já incluí as chaves SHA-1 e SHA-256 em meu projeto e inseri o json no aplicativo.

Estou testando tudo via emulador.

nas configurações do Firebase, tenho links dinâmicos e todos são válidos:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yeX.png)

Nas autenticações, tenho apenas este ativo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4E3M.png)

e estes são os domínios autorizados:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3JxM.png)

Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar

Comment: Joel, como estão as configurações de acesso no login? Você adicionou o "localhost" como domínio de redirecionamento do OAuth? Lá na tela do Firebase Auth, depois dos métodos de autenticação, veja se o localhost está na seção como domínios autorizados.